# Media streaming on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, streaming, media

I am writing a Win8 app that consumes media stored back in Azure/Web Server. I want to secure the download of the media to folks which are authenticated for my Windows 8 App and/or stream it.
What can be the architecture for this scenario?

What is better - Stream or secure download.

What is supported by Windows 8?

Also, I want to avoid Windows Media Services Streaming as I don't have that infrastructure.

Thanks,
Bhavik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [player framework for windows 8](http://playerframework.codeplex.com)

The Microsoft Media Platform's Player Framework is an open source video player that we continue to develop and evolve. It is available for Silverlight, HTML5, Windows Phone, Xbox, and now, in our latest release, Windows 8 applications. And it's fully open source!

The Player Framework supports a long list of advanced features including:
Adaptive streaming and advanced playback heuristics via the IIS Smooth Streaming Client SDK for Windows 8
Closed captioning support via SMPTE-TT and TTML
Advertising standards support including VAST, MAST, and VPAID
Advanced DVR-style playback
Robust skinning and styling
A number of other powerful features

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it!